# Import an Ant classpatch from another file

Tags: java, ant, build, build-process

I'm exploring the awesomeness of Ant 1.8.1's import ability. Here's my situation: I have a top-level Ant file (project.xml) that turns around and calls ant on another Ant file (say, neato_project.xml) which actually does the build, or clean or whatever.

I have 12 different project files that this top-level (project.xml) file can call, so I want to put a common classpath entry into the project.xml file that I can pass to the others to use as their individual classpaths.

How do I do that? I've been trying to play with import task, but I haven't gotten that figured out. I'm open to another approach if there's a better way to approach this problem in Ant.

Comment: What task are you using to invoke the other ant files? Both `ant` and `antcall` pass existing properties in by default. (Maybe show a snippet of your build files?)

Comment: I'm using ant. I may have a workaround by reversing my build process and passing the project name into a common build script, but it's kind of invasive. I'd feel better if I could minimize the impact of this change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import wasn't introduced in 1.8; it was enhanced in 1.8.  This is good because it means people like me have a couple years experience with import.

What I do:

1. constants.xml - the common strings and classpaths my build uses
2. build.xml - the main file imports #1 and #3
3. helper-project-1.xml - it has a clearer name, but that's hardly the poing
4. helper-project-2.xml, etc

I use this approach because I want build.xml to pass the constants.  I only keep them in a separate file for readability.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Your approach sounds like it's just what I'm looking for. Would you please point me to a simple and specific example on how to import those files?

Comment: Not to cite the manual, but I'm not doing anything complicated.  Just
<import file="${workspacedir}/${buildProject}/constants.xml" />